# Accessing a ManyToMany associated table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

### The goal

Access a [ManyToMany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many) associated table.

### The problem

I need to add roles to a user but the `UsersRoles` table isn't mapped by Entity Framework as a table: to access it, I need to do through `Users` table.

In other words, how can I add something to the `UsersRoles` table via C# if it is an association instead of a table?

Comment: This problem comes up way too many times, and there's thousands of tutorials out there about this.

Comment: Show me a few tutorials, @SOFanatic — I appreciate the references. Always that I post here on SO, I search the web about my subject. If there's no satisfatory results, so I come here to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it to one of the collection properties:

```
myUser.Roles.Add(someRole);
```

Comment: Hello, @SLaks. There's not an `Add()` method within my `Roles`.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge: Change it to `ICollection<T>`.